# Is there a way to direct two case to one block of code?

Tags: postgresql, conditional-statements, case

I want ot redirect two cases to one block of code. In other languages it is possible to just stack one after another the cases like in the code below. But postgres just do nothing in this case. Is there a way to do what I want?

```
VARIABLE_TYPE TEXT := 'BOOL'

CASE VARIABLE_TYPE

    WHEN 'INTEGER' THEN
        --a lot of code

    WHEN 'BOOL' THEN
    WHEN 'BOOLEAN' THEN
        --a lot of code

END CASE;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [generic version](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-conditional.html) of `CASE` expression like this:

```
VARIABLE_TYPE TEXT := 'BOOL'

CASE 
    WHEN VARIABLE_TYPE = 'INTEGER' THEN
        --a lot of code

    WHEN VARIABLE_TYPE = 'BOOL' OR
         VARIABLE_TYPE = 'BOOLEAN' THEN
        --a lot of code

END CASE;
```